# Pouring a new concrete chimney crown...should I DIY?

Tags: concrete, masonry, chimney

Just bought a home in Maryland with two brick masonry chimneys that both need crown repairs (and some repointing work). In my non-expert opinion, they're probably too far gone too patch or seal coat, and will need to be re-poured.

I worked as a house painter for a time, and I'm fairly comfortable with roof and ladder safety. I've also looked into the local building codes to make sure I'm both allowed to DIY and that I think I could handle the job. My plan would be to build a form and try to pour crowns that are up to code (or close to it) to replace the deteriorated crowns that were not built to modern standards to begin with.

It seems within my abilities to do, but I'm interested in the community opinion. The only thing I'm really on the fence about is that I have no experience with masonry or concrete repairs. For example, should I repoint the brick mortar before or after pouring the crown? What kind of concrete mix is best for the crown? What makes for a reliable bond break between the crown and the chase? What can I use to make the expansion gap around the flu liner that won't stick to the concrete? How do I get a put a drip edge on my concrete form? How deep in the crown should reinforcement material go? Do I need to extend my clay liners if those flues aren't being used?

Like I said, I'm fairly confident in my ability to tackle this, just need to figure out some of these things before I start. But if there's something I'm totally overlooking, I'm interested to know what others think about whether or not this is worth trying to DIY. For monetary reasons, my only other option is to try some bandaid fixes until we save up enough to have a contractor do it, but I'd rather not let it go through another winter looking like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're not new to SE. You should know that opinion based questions are off-topic at just about every site, and that multiple questions are also off-topic. Please edit and reformulate.

Comment: You've presented almost a dozen valid questions about the procedure. You can either go find each answer individually or watch a YouTube video or two such as this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sw70e5NZZYA. Yes, I agree that it sounds within your abilities to do this project yourself. Where you waiting for, a motivational cheer squad or something? Get going, the nights are getting colder and concrete needs a full 2 weeks of above 40°F to properly cure!

Comment: your home insurance might have different ideas about the DIY-ness of this job; mine (state farm) specified the exact same job's "work must be completed by a solid fuel technician."

Comment: Learning masonry repair /cement  on top of your chimney seems... not ideal.  Just lugging all the tools up there is a project.  Practice on the ground and get your tools in order first.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of observations.

That concrete cracked because it was applied too thin and probably no bonding agent was used.

Carefully read the minimum thickness instruction when choosing concrete.

Get and apply bonding agent.

Clearly you have to chisel off the loose concrete first.

Observe the minimum thickness guide, even at the edges which was clearly not done.

**Reinforced concrete method:**

To prevent cracking, get a mesh wire with aprox 1/4 inch or larger squares.

Cut it to dimension, and lay it over the chimney. Now apply concrete on top of the mesh.